How to avoid getting an unwanted team member into the Project?
Every year we have a company celbration. For this we put up a main attraction, which is a sort of sculpture of scaffold elements. From our 150 person strong company I need to put together a team of around 15 members, which will design, plan and build the thing. To Management it is important, that people join voluntarily. So I shall call for volunteers next month at the town hall meeting. Unfortunately there is a coworker who is really bad to work with, especially in this type of creative work. (I know from plenty of past bad experience) I want him to not join the team. However he has participated in quite many of these projects in the past. This time he is also eager to join.
How can I deal with this situation.

How much say do you have? Can you pick your team from the volunteers, or do you just have to take any warm body that shows up?

How many volunteers do you usually get? If you need 15 people, but 20 or more join, you can always decline help. And, since this individual has participated frequently, you can suggest that you'd like to extend the opportunity to other people in the company to be able to join the team instead.

If you really can't politely say "we already have enough people for this year's project", then you not going to get the answer you want.
Start planning for tasks to give them to keep them out of your way.
Assuming that you don't want to be the person that tells people to not volunteer, your best bet is how to mitigate your time together and their affect on the project.
I suppose/hope you already knew that random internet people couldn't just make this person go away. In this case, the best we could do is remind you of your options. Avoid and accept.
